# 404 not found, wrong urls even my mappings are correct

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have this two classes for app config:

```
 package com.spring.config;

   imports

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.spring")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());


    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    
    @Bean
    public DataSource myDataSource() {
        
        // create connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // set the jdbc driver
        try {
            myDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");       
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
        
        // for sanity's sake, let's log url and user ... just to make sure we are reading the data
        logger.info("jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info("jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        
        // set database connection props
        myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        
        // set connection pool props
        myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));     
        myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

        return myDataSource;
    }
    
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        
        return props;               
    }

    
    // need a helper method 
    // read environment property and convert to int
    
    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {
        
        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);
        
        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);
        
        return intPropVal;
    }   
    
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        
        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        
        // set the properties
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        
        // setup transaction manager based on session factory
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }   
    
}
```

---

```
    package com.spring.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { DemoAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

---

This is my `StudentController` class:

```
    package com.spring.app;

    imports

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listStudents(Model theModel) {

        // get customers from the service
        List<Student> theStudents = studentService.listStudents();

        // add the customers to the model
        theModel.addAttribute("students", theStudents);

        return "student-list";
    }



    @GetMapping("/showFormForAdd")
    public String showFormForAdd(Model theModel) {

        // create model attribute to bind form data
        Student theStudent = new Student();

        theModel.addAttribute("student", theStudent);

        return "add-student-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addNewStudent")
        public String addNewStudent (@ModelAttribute("student") Student theStudent){
            studentService.addNewStudent(theStudent);

            return "redirect:/student/list";
        }
    }
```

---

App goes like this when I run it:

First shows me two links because of this, that is okey:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/student/showFormForAdd/">Add student</a>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/student/list/">List students</a>
```

I click on add student and app give me form to enter fname, lname and email, that is fine:
Little code of that:

```
<form:form action="addNewStudent" modelAttribute="student" method="POST">

    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label>First name:</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Last name:</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Email:</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label></label></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" /></td>
        </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>


</form:form>
```

When I click save app show me `404 not found` and this is URL: `spring_project/student/showFormForAdd/addNewStudent` instead of `spring_project/student/list/` because as you can see I have this here, this is in `StudentController` class method is `addNewStudent`, code: `return "redirect:/student/list";`

I dont know why is this happening, did I forgot some config, my mappings is bad? What can be problem? I share my project on github so for mode code and review you can see it there:

[Github](https://github.com/jankostefan/spring_project)

Comment: Using a package corresponding to a DNS name you don't own, but someone else might (`com.spring` in your case) is poor practice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it doesn't solve my current problem.

Comment: @Stevan, try this: `<form:form action="/addNewStudent" modelAttribute="student" method="POST">`

Comment: Tried, doesnt work.